# Can I use flv file for video as a background?

Tags: css, html, video, background, flv

Is it possible to set up video in flv file as a background? I want to have website with video 100% wide and 100vh of height as a background for the whole content, something similar to this:
http://demosthenes.info/samples/polina.html

Comment: I recommend you just to convert video to different formats, to support all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set up video in flv file as a background?

Yes but you have to use Flash-Player plugin. You will also need to code in **[AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html)** using **[Flash CC](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash.html)** to make a program that loads the video file data. The program is saved as an **SWF** file (is the compiled program code). This SWF is then embedded into the HTML and you then use CSS layers (z-index) to position as background index.

**Now about your FLV file...** You are limiting yourself if you keep it in this format only. You should also convert it to MP4 and WebM formats. If you do this, you can have a video background built like the example you showed. Using a built-in browser decoder without the need for a Flash Player plugin (right click on the video and you'll see its not Flash Player related). This is most important for mobile web viewers where most browser apps cannot display Flash content (but only Flash can handle FLV on the web).

In your example link, they used a WebM file but you can do the same with MP4 filename instead. After converting you can even test using the example link's **[source code](http://view-source:http://demosthenes.info/samples/polina.html)**.

Try these links:

- **[Convert FLV to MP4 file](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4)**
- **[Convert FLV to WebM file](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-webm)**

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answer :) You've gave me summary of what I thought is right, but wasn't 100% sure. I know that I need more formats for video and MP4 + WebM should do the work. I was testing different conversion files to check how small they can be and still keep quality I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flv, but it's best to use three different formats when using video's on a website. Because not every browser supports the same files it't necessary to convert your file to these: .ogg, .mp4, .flv and .swf.

More detailed information here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-html5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash--net-9982